# Range sum with a while loop for an assignment

Tags: java, while-loop

I am new to Java and I'm trying to do a range sum with a while loop for an assignment. I need to use a while loop for this and the loop is not storing the total correctly and just adds the two values together.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the first number: ");

    int first = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the second number: ");

    int second = keyboard.nextInt();
    if( second < first) {
        System.out.println("The sum is 0");
    }
    else if(second > first) {
        int total = 0;
        while (first < second) {
            total = second + first;
            second = second - 1;
            first = first +1;
            total = second + first;//this does not give the correct total 
        }
    System.out.print("The sum is "+total++);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of telling us that you are getting the wrong sum, please tell us an expected input, the expected output, and the actual output.

Comment: Should you be doing ```total += first + second```, which is ```total = total + first + second```? I can only guess this is the problem because your'e overwriting the previous sum in a loop.
You should always provide more information though, so we can do more than guess.

Answer (score 0):

You are updating your total twice in the while loop, and you are changing both first and second variables in the loop.  It would be clearer to modify just one of the numbers.  I think a for loop is a little easier to read for a sum range.  Here is an example of one that sums inclusive of both ends:

```
for (int i = first; i <= second; i++) {
  total += i;
}
```

here is a fix for your while loop (with it being inclusive of both first and second):

```
while (first <= second) {
  total += first;
  first++;
}
```